# How to properly concatenate the values of Columns of a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable

In the following code, I noticed that Columns `A` and `B` show data.
However, columns `C` and `D` are empty. Why?

```
DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn A=_dt.Columns.Add("A");
DataColumn B=_dt.Columns.Add("B");
DataColumn C=_dt.Columns.Add("C",typeof(String),"A+B");
DataColumn D=_dt.Columns.Add("D",typeof(String),"A+'!'+B");

DataRow _dr=_dt.NewRow();
_dr["A"]="A";
_dr["B"]="B";

Console.WriteLine(_dr["A"]);
Console.WriteLine(_dr["B"]);
Console.WriteLine(_dr["C"]); //Shows blank-why? Expected AB
Console.WriteLine(_dr["D"]); //Shows blank-why? Expected A!B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the DataRow to the DataTable, that's when the [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression) is first evaluated:

These are calculated columns. When the `+` symbols is used with Columns of data type String, the values are concatenated.

> String Operators
>
> T*o concatenate a string, use the + character. The value of the
>   CaseSensitive property of the DataSet class determines whether string
>   comparisons are case-sensitive. However, you can override that value
>   with the CaseSensitive property of the DataTable class.*

```
DataRow _dr=_dt.NewRow();
_dr["A"]="A";
_dr["B"]="B";
_dt.Rows.Add(_dr);
```

As a note, the four lines above can be written as:

```
_dt.Rows.Add("A", "B");
```

The result is of course the same. The values of Columns `C` and `D` are not included in the `object[]` array, but generated by the Columns' Expressions.

Now it should output:

```
A
B
AB
A!B
```

Comment: Very clever answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarifications