# Fill DataGridView row with an SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

what I want to do is to fill up a row with a specific combination of data that are in a connected Access database.

So I Fill up my Rows like this:

```
DataRow dr = table.NewRow();    
dr[3] = Textbox1.Text;
table.Rows.Add(dr);
```

And this is basically just taking the text from a textbox and fills in the index 3 table row.

And what I want to do is to get two table data from the database that are connected with my rows in the DataGridView and just multiply them with each other. I can't really explain this clearly so here's an SQL query:

SELECT Number1 * Number2 FROM Numbers

And I want to fill up a DataGridView cell with Number1 and a cell with Number2 and also a cell with Number1 * Number2 but I don't know how could I do it in real code.

I have the idea that i should make these values as a double or string variables but I have no idea how.

Comment: [DataColumn.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression)

Comment: For example: [Correct event to calculate Cells values in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62291110/7444103) and a couple of note here: [How to properly concatenate the values of Columns of a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61787603/7444103) that may be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Could not your query be written as:

```
SELECT Number1, Number2, (Number1 * Number2) AS MyMult FROM MyTable
```

So, you would not need to loop, but just bind the resulting datatable to the GriView.

eg:
VB

```
dim strSQL as string
strSQL  = "SELECT Number1, Number2, (Number1 * Number2) AS MyMult FROM MyTable"
GridView1.datasource = MyRst(strSQL)
GridView1.databind()
```

c#

```
string strSQL;
strSQL = "SELECT Number1, Number2, (Number1 * Number2) AS MyMult FROM MyTable";
GridView1.datasource = MyRst(strSQL);
GridView1.databind();
```

For above, MyRst is just a handy routine that returns a datatable type.
(so you don't have to typle sqlCommand and connection object over and over).

Comment: Wrong platform :)

Comment: indeed, I did miss the winforms as opposed to asp.net and web forms. However, the answer and suggestion will and still does seem to apply equal well. (put the expression in the query).

Comment: Yes, `GridView1.databind();` is what is really out of place. -- Unrelated to my previous comment, since you mentioned: of course you can create a calculated Column/Field, it's also true that the value returned is *static*. If one of the active Columns values changes, the value is not updated. So, it applies more to a *report* than to a *dynamic control*, modified by a User or other external sources while the DataGridView is presented (thus, I proposed an `Expression`). Just a note; it's possible that the OP just wants pre-calculated values and nothing else.

Comment: Sure, if edit of the result is required? Then on row bind would be the ticket (I think it exists for winforms) - have to run but will update this post in a bit.

Comment: There's no Row binding notification, unfortunately. You're notified when the data binding is complete (the DataSource has been processed). There's the `CellValueChanged` event you can use, but, usually, you try to avoid that, if you can do the same thing elsewhere (e.g., with the source query), because, you know, WinForms Controls are be so performant and reactive, it's a pity to slow them down :). The Expression is applied by the DataColumn of the underlying DataTable, so you don't need to add code tied to event handlers, everything is automatic.